Application Installation issue from the Microsoft store
Our application was developed using UWP and submitted to the Microsoft store. According to the Microsoft partner center, there has been a significant drop in the installation of our app (the decline has been starting since May). Based on Acquisition fannel, the drop occurs between Page view to install attempts.  How can I investigate the cause of this drop? Are there any tools available to investigate issues like this (issues associated with install attempts, Incomplete install e.t.c.)?

Do some "viewing", etc. yourself and watch the stats. I'd expect the ratios to be the same, (views : installs). But if there are 0 views ... MS is changing shelves again.

@GerrySchmitz thanks for reply. Do you think that the data will be updated immediately? I have tried but the views count has not increased. I want to note, that we are installing our app successfully, on different devices with different OS. Based on the Acquisition fannel, our users have installing issues, and we want to understand the cause. What do you mean "MS is changing shelves again"?

There are store analytics for your app with charts over time.  The MS store, IMO, is a disaster in organization. I have to find my own apps "by name" since there is no structure  to their non-organization of content. What worked a month ago (navigation) fails in the coming months.

@GerrySchmitz Do you know of any tools or services that can help sort out these issues? What are some potential reasons that could cause this problem?

During this period, the size of our bundle increased to 800 MB. Could this be the reason for the decrease in installations?
Can you suggest a way to research and understand the issue? I’m unsure of the best way to proceed.


I've never had reports of "installation" issues. Every UWP "compile" is in effect an "install" (it winds up on your machine as an app; if it's in the store, it becomes downloadable for you; as developer. I've sideloaded to my own tablet, etc. I package "one bundle"; targeting every device.  I guess you should "buy" your own app with a "clean account" and see what happens ... (Maybe your "OS target level" is too high ? low ?)

@GerrySchmitz Maybe there’s been some misunderstanding. Our app was published a few years ago, and as the developer, I have no problem installing it. I can install it directly from the Microsoft Store. The issue is with the 'acquisition funnel' analytics report in the Microsoft Partner Center, which reflects the behavior of end users, not me as the developer.
I don’t believe the target OS version is set too high, as our target version is 22H2, which has been in use for quite some time. However, we’ve noticed a significant drop in installations over the past few months.

As I said, If MS has "buried" your app, by "re-locating" it in the store; so that normal "browsing" will not find it, then it will not get viewed or installed. I mentioned the "view / install ratio"; I can't see your stats, and therefore cannot identify any patterns. What is a "user"? Get a "friend" to try and install it on their machine. "Testing".

Toggle the "one day free trial" option; for a limited time. That should move you on some charts (I suspect). Add a "new" app. It should show up on "What's new". etc.

I am having the same issue since a few weeks
